# Difficulty with scope

Tags: javascript, google-maps, scope

I have google maps javascript code that doesn't behave, and I think it has to do with scope, but I cannot figure it out. Here are the relevant pieces of code:

```
function initialize() {
    google.maps.event.addListener(MapArea, 'click', showIW);

    function showIW(event) {

        function moreInfo(){
            //...
        }
        infoWindow.setContent(moreInfo());
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This does NOT work (moreInfo is undefined), however, this does:

```
function initialize() {
    google.maps.event.addListener(MapArea, 'click', showIW);

    function showIW(event) {
        infoWindow.setContent(moreInfo());
    }
}

function moreInfo(){
//...
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Why is moreInfo() undefined in the first scenario, even though I define moreInfo() before I call it?

Comment: [Works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Qbp54/1/)

Comment: Could you try it with `C = function(){...`

Comment: are you using this in a webpage or what else?

Comment: show your actual code

Comment: read more on closures here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon, yes, I am using it in a page.  It is a google maps application, where A() is the initialize function, B() is an infoWindow and C() is an overlay

Comment: @AmitJoki.  I edited the question to show the code.

Comment: Define "does not work". Presumably the first line should start with `function initialize() {...`.

Comment: The code you have posted is not the code you are running, *moreInfo* is defined in both cases. Perhaps the real code has different spelling or capitalisation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are just defining the `B` function an not calling it.

So, Whatever inside `B` will never execute. I don't see you call A either, and since you don't return anything, it is `undefined`.

You can use self-executing function or just call it.

```
function A() {
    function B() {
        function C(){
            //...
        }
        // call C()
    }
    B(); // you call it here, which in turn calls C
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I left those parts out because they are not the problem.  I edited my question.